# Selenium Edge mode IE in python, preference to auto donwload PDF

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need a preference option that makes the pdfs download automatically, but I need it to be with this options class:
**from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options**
because i use this parameters:

```
options = Options()
options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True
options.add_argument("--ie-mode-force=IE5")
options.attach_to_edge_chrome = True
```

I tried this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver import Edge

edgeOption = EdgeOptions()
edgeOption.use_chromium = True

edgeOption.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
    "download.default_directory": "C:\\Downloads",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False
})
```